# Scrape Websites with Python + Beautiful Soup 4 All pages

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i am very new to Python, and i am trying to Scrape data from a website, but i need  all pages, so far i have :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get ("http://www.somesite.com/records/08-jan-2016/")
r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
full_info = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-sm-10"})

for item in full_info : print (item.text)
```

This code prints data from current page, how can i manage to take data from all pages , and exported to a file.

Best regards

Comment: Define "all pages". Are they links that can be accessed recursively? (i.e. could you get them with `wget -r`) Are they different URLs? Do they link to each other? How would you normally get the links? You seem to have BeautifulSoup pretty down. You can just use `open` to write to a file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, the url's are formatted as dates  :

"http://www.somesite.com/records/08-jan-2016/"
"http://www.somesite.com/records/09-jan-2016/"
"http://www.somesite.com/records/10-jan-2016/"

etc, until today, at the end of each page there is a button for previews and next date.

Comment: How do you know which dates are valid? Are you just going to assume all dates, or do you have a list?

Comment: i have check and validate that all dates from 08-jan-2016 to 29-mar-2016 exist.

Comment: So it seems your question is more "how do I iterate through these dates in this format"?

Comment: I do not understand what is the point of your question, it is clearly that you understand what i want to do, can you help?

Comment: I was making an assertion. If it's correct, then your problem doesn't actually have anything to do with website scraping, it's about date formatting. This is for future reference on how to ask a good question. You want to ask the problem you actually have, not what the answer to that problem solves. It's not at all obvious from the question given what the *real* question is - which is date formatting.

Comment: i do not know how to scape the data from the other pages, either the url is with date format or any other format, i just manage to scrape data from a singe page, and i am asking how can i get the data from other pages too....... what is the point of this conversation my friend? the title of the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library for date arithmetic - it's what it's designed to do.
However, since [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)'s [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) is locale-based, it's safer to do the construction of the string manually, unless you intend on running this on a known locale that matches the website's.

```
import datetime
MONTH_NAMES = {1: 'jan', 2: 'feb', 3: 'mar'}  # and so on
ONE_DAY = datetime.timedelta(1)

def date_strings(first_date, last_date):
    current_date = first_date
    while current_date <= last_date:
        yield '{0.day:02}-{1}-{0.year:04}'.format(
            current_date, MONTH_NAMES[current_date.month])
        # If running on a US locale, you can just use:
        # yield current_date.strftime('%d-%b-%Y').lower()
        current_date += ONE_DAY

first_date = datetime.date(2016, 1, 8)
last_date = datetime.date(2016, 3, 29)

for date_string in date_strings(first_date, last_date):
    print(date_string)
    # Do whatever scraping you need using date_string
```

Answer (score 0):

So to add to the question raised in the comments, how to iterate through multiple dates.  I'm not the most proficient programmer, but I would create a **dictionary** with the **key:value** => **month:number of days** in the month.  Then you could create a nested loop to create strings to append to the url.

```
dates = {"jan":31, "feb":29, "mar":31}
for month in dates:
  for day in range(dates[month]):
    url = "https://www.somepage.com/{0}-{1}-2016".format(str(day+1), month)
    req = requests.get(url)
    ...
```